# How to make vuetify checkbox react only if clicked on the box, not the label?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a simple checkbox with injected template for the label slot, as shown below:

```
<v-checkbox
  v-model="selectAllRequired"
  class="not-so-isolated">
  <template v-slot:label>
    <button
      @click="changeOrder">
      <v-img
        max-width="14"
        class="image list-sort-icon"
        :src="directionIcon" />
      <span class="list-title">ROLA</span>
  </button>
  </template>
</v-checkbox>
```

I have specified some behavior when someone clicks on the mentioned label. The problem is that box is used for some other job. How to tick the checkbox only if the box was clicked, and ignore label-clicking? Is it possible? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on top of your `changeOrder(event)` method.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/4ya9gqps/